# Unsupported link: Spotify, Discord.py Music Bot

Tags: python, pip, discord.py, spotify, youtube-dl

**I'm making a discord bot. But I'm having spotify issue.**

its says

> **"spotdl: error: unrecognized arguments: -s: (music link)"**

**I've installed pip youtubedl,spotdl, every pip I needed.
I'm making this bot for my discord server.**

Please help me.

I've learned this from this  [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvEldmLnuhU) link. In this tutorial, bot was working fine. But not mine. What should I do now?

```
    import os
    import shutil
    from os import system
    import discord
    import youtube_dl
    from discord.ext import commands
    from discord.utils import get
    
    TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
    BOT_PREFIX = '.'
    
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Logged in as: " + bot.user.name + "\n")
    
    
    @bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['j', 'joi'])
    async def join(ctx):
        global voice
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
    
        await voice.disconnect()
    
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
            print(f"The bot has connected to {channel}\n")
    
        await ctx.send(f"Joined {channel}")
    
    
    @bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['l', 'lea'])
    async def leave(ctx):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.disconnect()
            print(f"The bot has left {channel}")
            await ctx.send(f"Left {channel}")
        else:
            print("Bot was told to leave voice channel, but was not in one")
            await ctx.send("Don't think I am in a voice channel")
    
    
    @bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
    async def play(ctx, url: str):
    
        def check_queue():
            Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
            if Queue_infile is True:
                DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
                length = len(os.listdir(DIR))
                still_q = length - 1
                try:
                    first_file = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
                except:
                    print("No more queued song(s)\n")
                    queues.clear()
                    return
                main_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
                song_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + "\\" + first_file)
                if length != 0:
                    print("Song done, playing next queued\n")
                    print(f"Songs still in queue: {still_q}")
                    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
                    if song_there:
                        os.remove("song.mp3")
                    shutil.move(song_path, main_location)
                    for file in os.listdir("./"):
                        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
    
                    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
                    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
                    voice.source.volume = 100.00
    
                else:
                    queues.clear()
                    return
    
            else:
                queues.clear()
                print("No songs were queued before the ending of the last song\n")
    
    
    
        song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
        try:
            if song_there:
                os.remove("song.mp3")
                queues.clear()
                print("Removed old song file")
        except PermissionError:
            print("Trying to delete song file, but it's being played")
            await ctx.send("ERROR: Music playing")
            return
    
    
        Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
        try:
            Queue_folder = "./Queue"
            if Queue_infile is True:
                print("Removed old Queue Folder")
                shutil.rmtree(Queue_folder)
        except:
            print("No old Queue folder")
    
        await ctx.send("Getting everything ready now")
    
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'quiet': True,
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
        try:
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                print("Downloading audio now\n")
                ydl.download([url])
        except:
            print("FALLBACK: youtube-dl does not support this URL, using Spotify (This is normal if Spotify URL)")
            c_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            system("spotdl -f " + '"' + c_path + '"' + " -s " + url)
    
        for file in os.listdir("./"):
            if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                name = file
                print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
                os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
        voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
        voice.source.volume = 0.07
    
        nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
        await ctx.send(f"Playing: {nname[0]}")
        print("playing\n")
    
    
    @bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['pa', 'pau'])
    async def pause(ctx):
    
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
        if voice and voice.is_playing():
            print("Music paused")
            voice.pause()
            await ctx.send("Music paused")
        else:
            print("Music not playing failed pause")
            await ctx.send("Music not playing failed pause")
    
    
    @bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['r', 'res'])
    async def resume(ctx):
    
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
        if voice and voice.is_paused():
            print("Resumed music")
            voice.resume()
            await ctx.send("Resumed music")
        else:
            print("Music is not paused")
            await ctx.send("Music is not paused")
    
    
    @bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['s', 'sto'])
    async def stop(ctx):
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
        queues.clear()
    
        queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
        if queue_infile is True:
            shutil.rmtree("./Queue")
    
        if voice and voice.is_playing():
            print("Music stopped")
            voice.stop()
            await ctx.send("Music stopped")
        else:
            print("No music playing failed to stop")
            await ctx.send("No music playing failed to stop")
    
    
    queues = {}
    
    @bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['q', 'que'])
    async def queue(ctx, url: str):
        Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
        if Queue_infile is False:
            os.mkdir("Queue")
        DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
        q_num = len(os.listdir(DIR))
        q_num += 1
        add_queue = True
        while add_queue:
            if q_num in queues:
                q_num += 1
            else:
                add_queue = False
                queues[q_num] = q_num
    
        queue_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + f"\song{q_num}.%(ext)s")
    
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'quiet': True,
            'outtmpl': queue_path,
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
        try:
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                print("Downloading audio now\n")
                ydl.download([url])
        except:
            print("FALLBACK: youtube-dl does not support this URL, using Spotify (This is normal if Spotify URL)")
            q_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
            system(f"spotdl -ff song{q_num} -f " + '"' + q_path + '"' + " -s " + url)
    
    
        await ctx.send("Adding song " + str(q_num) + " to the queue")
    
        print("Song added to queue\n")
    
    
    @bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['n', 'nex'])
    async def next(ctx):
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
        if voice and voice.is_playing():
            print("Playing Next Song")
            voice.stop()
            await ctx.send("Next Song")
        else:
            print("No music playing")
            await ctx.send("No music playing failed")
    bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Md Sadman Muhtasim Billah!

Well, it seems like the problem is actually in the URL you're submitting, as it don't recognize the '-s' *argument*, not the parameter itself.
So you should probably try the same URL he uses in the YouTube video you sent, to test it. Or try other links.
I couldn't find a flaw in the code, and it really is the same used in the YT tutorial.

Hope I helped. :)